# Error when creating a Partial View in Visual Studio 2012 Express with Razor

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, strongly-typed-view

I am creating a view in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express and I want it to be a strongly-typed partial view, but I am getting the following error:

> C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress\Item Templates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML\Empty.tt(-1,1) : error : There was a problem getting an AppDomain to run the transformation from the host. The process cannot continue.

I have not had any trouble creating views that are not partial views, strongly-typed or not.

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off then on again?"

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy `"Have you tried turning it off then on again?"` <-- the first principle of computer science ;)

Comment: restarting didn't work for me, see my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637632/exception-when-adding-a-view-to-mvc3/27259065#27259065

Answer (score 47):

Is simple...
Just **restart Visual Studio**.

http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/07/appdomain-process-cannot-continue.html#.UQwtQs6mg1I

Comment: For anyone with VS2012 Update 3 , this is happening to me when I sometimes click on a method in a controller and click on "Add View" ,  but indeed the restart of visual studio does fix this.  thx

Comment: Worked in VS 2019 for me as well

Answer (score 4):

I was using Visual Studio 2013 Professional and had the same issue and none of the following worked for me-

- Restarted VS- didn't helped
- There was no `<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />` in devenv.exe.config file
- Reinstalled Nuget Package Manager from VS > Tools > Extensions and Updates
- Reinstalled MVC4 from Microsoft

Then I repaired my VS installation from Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs and my issue was resolved. I don't know what went wrong but this certainly needs attention by Microsoft Guys. Hope my answer helps out somebody in need.

Comment: Your problem is outside of the 99% of the problems that solves the first principle of computer science: restarting. Sad.

Comment: @pabloker You're absolutely right, this truly took so much important time repairing visual studio installation

Answer (score 2):

I was using VS12 and Updated to VS13, i was unable to create views and was getting the above error, I just updated Nuget Package Manager by going in Tool --> Extension and Updates and everything worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

As I was having same issue, I realized that this workaround may work for some of us, but... In my case, it did not work. But changing the devenv.exe.config, removing the line

```
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />
```

did the trick. Hope it helps those like me, need to have that anoying thing for some older solutions... ;)