# mvc Add controller error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

hello I'm adding a controller and  I see this error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might seem obvious, but have you tried restarting VS?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling/re-installing Nuget

Answer (score 0):

Simple.Restart Visual Studio.

Refer the below sites:

http://flirtingdotnet.blogspot.in/2013/07/there-was-problem-getting-app-domain-to.html

[Error when Creating a Partial View in Visual Studio 2012 Express with Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653039/error-when-creating-a-partial-view-in-visual-studio-2012-express-with-razor)

http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/07/appdomain-process-cannot-continue.html#.Uvnnts5sFWV

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736308/vs-11-error-when-attempting-to-add-new-controller-to-project.

You will get an idea on this type of errors

Answer (score 0):

try on of these solutions

- restart VS
- uninstall/re-install ASP.Net MVC4
- uninstall/re-install Nuget